# how to achivie double tap Zoom for API 2.2?

Tags: android

I have Relative Layout whose background is static Image and many ImageViews as subchild. Now how to achieve double tap zoom on the background of the relative layout. User will click on the Background image anywhere and it will get zoom.

How will I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

show image in webview.  see this example...

```
String html = new String();
    html = ("<html><BODY  ><table  style='margin-top:100px;'  align='center'><tr><td><img src=\""+path+"\" width=\""+800+"px\" height=\""+800+"px\" ></td></tr></table> </BODY></html>" );

    webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/data/data/com.dharani.jorTablet.Fragments/",
           html,
           "text/html",
           "utf-8",
           "");
```